# Windows Azure Diagnostics Error:

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

I am working with Windows Azure Diagnostics. I add the below code in Webrol.cs

try

```
        {

            string wadConnectionString = "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString";

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(wadConnectionString));



            RoleInstanceDiagnosticManager roleInstanceDiagnosticManager = storageAccount.CreateRoleInstanceDiagnosticManager(RoleEnvironment.DeploymentId, RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Role.Name, RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id);

            DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration config = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();



            //Windows Azure logs

            config.Logs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1D);

            config.Logs.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = LogLevel.Undefined;



            //IIS 7.0 logs

            config.Directories.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1D);



            ////Failed Request logs

            config.Directories.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1D);



            //Windows Event logs

            // config.WindowsEventLog.DataSources.Add("System!*");

            config.WindowsEventLog.DataSources.Add("Application!*");

            config.WindowsEventLog.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1D);



            ////Crash dumps

            CrashDumps.EnableCollection(true);





            //update the config with changes

            roleInstanceDiagnosticManager.SetCurrentConfiguration(config);

        }

        catch (Exception ee)

        {

            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceWarning("Diagnostics failed");



        }
```

and the remaining neccesary things in Web.config and the connection string in the .cscfg file. 
Now I am able to log the Diagnostics in the from the Development environment using the Deployment Storage. But when i host the same application in Cloud I am not able to log the Diagnostics. I am getting an error like

"500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."

I tried by changing Copy local to true for the namespaces, but that doesn't work. 
I want the application to work in the deployment environment.
If anyone have any idea to resolve this please reply me.

Thanks  in advance.

Comment: When deploying to the cloud are you setting the value of "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" to be a connection string to an actual storage account?

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks like you are not changing the connection string for "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString". You can change this in the settings for the web role project or you service configuration file. Set it to your account name and key.  I normally do this with a build script so I can change this when I push to production. You can check out the post [here](http://scottdensmore.typepad.com/blog/2011/02/another-update-for-the-deployment-scripts-for-windows-azure.html) and the code [here](https://github.com/scottdensmore/AzureDeploySample).